# Find modulus of $\frac{|z_1-z_2|}{|1-(z_1)(\overline{z_2})|}$

Tags: complex-numbers

If $z_1$ and $z_2$ are two different complex numbers and $\lvert z_1\rvert=1 $ then find 
$$
\frac{\lvert z_1-z_2 \rvert}{\lvert 1-z_1\bar{z_2} \rvert}
$$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/506058/show-that-left-cfrac-alpha-beta1-bar-alpha-beta-right-1-when

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $|z_1| = |\bar{z_1}| = 1$, we have 
\begin{align*}
\frac{\lvert z_1-z_2 \rvert}{\lvert 1-z_1\bar{z_2} \rvert} &= \frac{|\bar{z_1}|\lvert z_1-z_2 \rvert}{\lvert 1-z_1\bar{z_2} \rvert} \\
&= \frac{\lvert \bar{z_1}z_1-\bar{z_1}z_2 \rvert}{\lvert 1-z_1\bar{z_2} \rvert}\\
&=\frac{\lvert 1-\bar{z_1}z_2 \rvert}{\lvert 1-z_1\bar{z_2} \rvert}\\
&=\frac{\overline{\lvert 1-\bar{z_1}z_2 }\rvert}{\lvert 1-z_1\bar{z_2} \rvert}\\
&=\frac{\lvert 1-{z_1}\bar{z_2} \rvert}{\lvert 1-z_1\bar{z_2} \rvert}\\
&=1
\end{align*}

Comment: Yes , I got it already, thanks mate

Answer (score 3):

$$\left|\dfrac{z_1-z_2}{1-z_1\bar{z_2}}\right|= \left|\dfrac{\overline{z_1-z_2}}{1-z_1\bar{z_2}}\right|= \left|\dfrac{\overline{z_1}-\overline{z_2}}{1-z_1\bar{z_2}}\right|=\dfrac1{|z_1|}\cdot\left|\dfrac{z_1\overline{z_1}-z_1\overline{z_2}}{1-z_1\bar{z_2}}\right|$$

Now $z_1\cdot\overline{z_1}=|z_1|^2$

Comment: Can you explain the last step pls? I am not able to understand it

Comment: @VankshuBansal, Multiplied the numerator & teh denominator by $|z_1|$

Comment: Okay, and the answer will involve$|z_2|$ right?

Comment: @VankshuBansal, No, observe the second modulus

Comment: I'm sorry , I can't get you, I'm extremely new to this topic

Comment: @VankshuBansal Note that $$\;|z_1\overline{z_1}-z_1\overline{z_2}|=||z_1|^2-z_1\overline{z_2}|=|1-z_1 \overline{z_2}|$$

Comment: @donAntonio there's some error in your typing

Comment: @VankshuBansal I'm looking at it right now and it looks fine...

Comment: Oh yeah, I got you, thank you so much, really appreciated :):)