# Find the value of $\frac {|B-A| }{|1-\overline AB|}$ where $|B| = 1$.

Tags: complex-numbers

> If $A$ and $B$ are two different complex numbers and $|B| = 1$, find the value of
>   $$\frac {|B-A| }{|1-\overline AB|}$$
>   where, as usual, $\overline A$ denotes the conjugate of $A$.

If possible please don't tell me the entire answer just tell me from where to begin.

Comment: Hint:  $B\times \overline B=1$.

Comment: Note:  I reformatted your post, replacing your $A'$ with $\overline A$, the standard notation for complex conjugate.  If you prefer it the way you wrote it, just click on "edit" and undo my change.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/506058/show-that-left-cfrac-alpha-beta1-bar-alpha-beta-right-1-when

Answer (score 0):

Note that $|\overline{B}|=|B|=1$ and
$$|1-\overline{A}B|=|1-\overline{A}B|\cdot|\overline{B}|=|(1-\overline{A}B)\cdot\overline{B}|=|\overline{B}-\overline{A}|B|^2|=|\overline{B}-\overline{A}|.$$
Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:)**

$$\left(\frac {|B-A| }{|1-\overline AB|}\right)^2=\dfrac{B-A}{1-\overline AB}\dfrac{\overline B-\overline A}{1-A\overline B}$$
now multiply and simplify!