# Problem with a Moebius transformation from disk to itself

Tags: complex-analysis

I need to show that a) every Möbius transformation that maps the disk onto itself can be written as $g(z)=e^{i\theta}\frac{z-z_0}{\bar{z_0}z-1}$, and b) that this function maps the unit disk onto the unit disk. I'm currently trying to make sense of the last part. Taking modules I get the following result: $|z|^2+|z_0|^2<1+|z||z_0|$, and I have been stuck there since. How can I prove this inequality given that $|z|,|z_0|<1$?

Comment: Without any hypothesis concerning $z_0$?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show that $\left|\frac{\alpha - \beta}{1-\bar{\alpha}\beta}\right| < 1$ when $|\alpha|,|\beta| < 1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/506058/show-that-left-frac-alpha-beta1-bar-alpha-beta-right-1-when)

Answer (score 1):

$$|g(z)|^2=\frac{|z-z_0|^2}{|\overline{z_0}z-1|^2}
=\frac{|z|^2+|z_0|^2-(z\overline{z_0}+\overline{z}z_0)}
{|zz_0|^2+1-(z\overline{z_0}+\overline{z}z_0)}{}
$$
Both numerator and denominator are positive, and denominator minus
numerator is
$$1+|zz_0|^2-|z|^2-|z_0|^2=(1-|z^2|)(1-|z_0^2|)>0$$
whenever $z$ and $z_0$ are in the open unit disc.