# Given $\left|a\right|<1$ and $\left|b\right|<1$, prove that $\left|\frac{a+b}{1+ab}\right|<1$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, contest-math

Here is my question:

> Let $a$ and $b$ be real numbers satisfying $\left|a\right|<1$ and $\left|b\right|<1$, prove that $\left|\frac{a+b}{1+ab}\right|<1$.

Her is my attempt:

- It is easy to note that $1+ab>0$.
- We can rewrite the inequality into $-1<\frac{a+b}{1+ab}<1$.

From here I can’t see the next step to prove it. Any suggestions?

Comment: **Hint :** This looks like a very well-know trigonometric formula : $\tan(x+y)=...$.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Interesting! I’ll give it a try.

Comment: Tell me if you need more details !

Comment: @TheSilverDoe I don't see where to go with that.. I mean I know that

$$\tan(x+y) = \frac{\tan x + \tan y}{1- \tan x \tan y}$$

But then what?

I'm not OP btw :p

Comment: @User Ok I wrote an answer :)

Comment: Note that this is a special case of an inequality for *complex* numbers: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/506058/42969.

Answer (score 3):

we have to prove $$|a+b|<|1+ab|$$

or $$a^2+b^2+2ab< 1+a^2b^2+2ab$$

or $$(a^2-1)(1-b^2)< 0$$ which is true because $|a|<1$,$|b|<1$

Comment: @Bernard thank you fixed it

Answer (score 2):

We know that $-1<a<1$ and $-1<b<1$.

Therefore,

- $(1-a)(1-b)>0\Longrightarrow (1+ab)-(a+b)>0\Longrightarrow 1+ab>a+b$
- $(1+a)(1+b)>0\Longrightarrow (1+ab)+(a+b)>0\Longrightarrow 1+ab>-(a+b)$

We get $$\left|1+ab\right|=1+ab>\left|a+b\right|$$, which is equivalent to $$\left|\frac{a+b}{1+ab}\right|<1$$
QED.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

Because $|a|,|b| < 1$, then there exists $u,v$ such that $a=\tanh(u)$ and $b=\tanh(v)$. Then
$$\left| \frac{a+b}{1+ab}\right| = \left| \frac{\tanh(u)+\tanh(v)}{1+\tanh(u)\tanh(v)}\right| = \left|\tanh \left(u+v \right)\right| <1$$

Comment: Very neat! ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

We have that

$$\left|\frac{a+b}{1+ab}\right|<1 \iff -1-ab\le a+b \le1+ab$$

and

$$-1-ab\le a+b \iff a+ab+b +1 \ge 0 \iff (a+1)(b+1) \ge 0$$

$$ a+b \le1+ab \iff a-ab+b-1\le 0 \iff (a-1)(b-1) \le 0$$

Comment: Thank you very much